# Hibernate : No identifier specified for entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I've developed a simple web application which connects to MySQL through hibernate. At a point, I was even successful in creating a connection and inserting the java object in the DB. However, I did some changes thereafter to meet my project needs and there I messed up the things. I am receiving this error "No identifier specified for entity" no matter how much I try to debug it. I even created a new project from scratch but in vain. Please help me out here in identifying what I am doing wrong.

```
   package com.proj.beandb;

   import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
   import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
   import javax.persistence.Column;
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.Table;

   import org.hibernate.Session;
   import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
   import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

   @ManagedBean
   @SessionScoped
   @Entity
   @Table(name="dbstat")
   public class Hibernate 
  {
  @Id
  @Column(name="first_name")
  private static String fname;

@Column(name="last_name")
private static String lname;

  public Hibernate(){}

   public Hibernate(String fname, String lname) 
      {
      Hibernate.fname = fname;
      Hibernate.lname = lname;
      }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

             // create session factory
             SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                               .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                               .buildSessionFactory();

             // create session
             Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

             try {       
                // create a student object
                System.out.println("Creating new object");
                Hibernate tempRec = new Hibernate("bah", "blah");

                // start a transaction
                session.beginTransaction();

                // save the object
                session.save(tempRec);

                // commit transaction
                session.getTransaction().commit();

                System.out.println("Done!");
             }
             finally {
                factory.close();
             }
          }

           public String getFname() {
                  return fname;
               }

               public void setFname(String fname) {
                  Hibernate.fname = fname;
               }

               public String getLname() {
                  return lname;
               }

               public void setLname(String lname) {
                  Hibernate.lname = lname;
               }
      }
```

`

Comment: Update your full stack trace so that we can find where is error

Comment: In order to use the string field as an id you need to put the below annotation @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid") @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2") @Column(name = "PR_KEY") private String prKey;

Comment: The above is an example you need to change it as per your requirements

Comment: Please include your hibernate.cfg.xml file in your post.  Your session factory build code adds an annotated Student class, but that isn't included as well; yet you're using a Hibernate entity.  How is this entity being mapped into Hibernate?  Via XML?

Comment: @LearningPhase Your suggestion is not correct. `@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")` specifies how to generate ids automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It is a really a big mistake to use `static` fields as properties of a persistent class.

```
@Id
@Column(name="first_name")
private static String fname;

@Column(name="last_name")
private static String lname;
```

should be

```
@Id
@Column(name="first_name")
private String fname;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lname;
```

You don't need it, because of it is not a Hibernate related stuff

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
```

You add `Student` class with `addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)`, maybe you need to add `Hibernate` class instead.

And please don't put `main()` in the persistent class.  You need to have `Hibernate` class and, for an example, `HibernateTest` class with `main()`.